# Adapt switch method to a listView that delete files in internal memory of the phone

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview which display a list of files (without filename extension) stored in the internal memory of the phone.
Then I have implement the `OnItemLongClickListener` that allow the user to delete a file.

`OnItemLongClickListener` works with the "switch" statement.

because position of the items in the list view will change every time a file will be deleted, I would like to implement  a rule that check if the name of the file match the related file, no matter if name of the file is moved in case 0, case 1 and so on.

To be clear:

Initial Listview:

```
    switch          Listview items         related file to delete
    case 0;               A                          A.map
    case 1;               B                          B.map
    case 2;               C                          C.map
    case 3;               D                          D.map
```

Listview after B has been deleted:

```
    switch          Listview items         related file to delete
    case 0;               A                          A.map
    case 1;               C                          C.map
    case 2;               D
```

Now, if before I wrote a rule at case 1 which was to delete B.map, it works fine.
But now item C have the same rule of case 1 , and rule does not match.

Because I am new to android, I don't know how to dove this problem.

Can somebody help me?

This is the Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/osmdroid/tiles/");
    File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
    String[] theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {

        String temp = filelist[i].getName();
       theNamesOfFiles[i] = temp.substring(0, temp.lastIndexOf('.'));

    }
    Arrays.sort(theNamesOfFiles);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_row, theNamesOfFiles);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        // setting onItemLongClickListener and passing the position to the function
                  @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {

                      switch(position){

                      case 0:{

                          }

                      break;

                      case 1:{

                          }
                          break;

                      case 2:{    


                          }
                          break;

                      case 3:{



                          }
                          break;

                      case 4:{

                          }

                          break;
                      }
            return true;
        }
    });
}



public void doDeleteFile(int position){

    File fileToDelete = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/osmdroid/tiles/", "A.map");

    if(!fileToDelete.isDirectory()){

        try{
            if(fileToDelete.delete()){  

                System.out.println("File delete operation success");
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("File delete operation failed");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception :"+ex.getMessage());
        }

    }else{

        System.out.println("It is  not a file");

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

First I will have a data structure about the items.

```
public class MyFile {
    File file;
    String fileName;

    public MyFile(File file)
    {
        this.file = file;
        this.fileName = file.getName();
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.fileName;
    }
}
```

`toString()` method is important. That method gives the text in the `ListView` in the `ArrayAdapter`.

Then I would initialize the adapter like this.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyFile>(this, R.layout.list_row, arrayOfMyFileObjects);
```

And lastly in `onItemLongClick()` function you can get the respective MyFile object like this

```
MyFile item = adapter.getItem(position);
```

And then you can delete using `deleteFile(item.file);`

I think the below code should do it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<MyFile> adapter;

public void list() {

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/osmdroid/tiles/");
    File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
    ArrayList<MyFile> theNamesOfFiles = new ArrayList<MyFile>();
    for (File temp : filelist) {
        theNamesOfFiles.add(new MyFile(temp));
    }
    Collections.sort(theNamesOfFiles, new Comparator<MyFile>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(MyFile lhs, MyFile rhs) {
            return lhs.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.toString());
        }
    });
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyFile>(this, R.layout.list_row,
            theNamesOfFiles);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

    list();

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        // setting onItemLongClickListener and passing the position to the
        // function
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {

            doDeleteFile(adapter.getItem(position).file);

            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void doDeleteFile(File fileToDelete) {
    if (!fileToDelete.isDirectory()) {

        try {
            if (fileToDelete.delete()) {

                System.out.println("File delete operation success");
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("File delete operation failed");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception :" + ex.getMessage());
        }

    } else {

        System.out.println("It is  not a file");

    }

}

public class MyFile {
    File file;
    String fileName;

    public MyFile(File file)
    {
        this.file = file;
        this.fileName = file.getName();
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.fileName;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have post the whole activity so you can have a clear view of my problem. I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: In your first code, MyClass is not in the MainActivity? i am new to android, does it is an object?

Comment: I have provided an example. Try to run it. If you got any error, they should be easy to fix. You can ask here again.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly! thank you thank you thank you! i would like  to hug you! you really have saved my day.

Comment: No problem at all. You should learn how to store whole information in just one array using custom objects. Have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

when you deleted your item remove it from array also and then call notifyDataSetChange() on adapter after updating the array item

No need to check for name.You can do it by position

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the function i use to delete files, allow to delete only a specific file. I would like to adapt this function, but i don't know how do it

Comment: i have add the function t delete file as you can see